# How to force a git merge conflict

Tags: git

When you have merge conflicts in git, they appear in the file like this:

```
<<<< 
  old
  old
====
  new
  new
>>>>
```

Now, I have some changes on `origin/master` I am going to merge into my local `master` branch. If I just merge them normally, the new lines will just appear nicely into the file, since there are no conflicts.

However, I want changes to appear like those merge conflicts above, so I can see both the old and new lines where the conflicts are, surrounded by `<<<<` and `>>>>`, review every change manually and delete stuff that should go away.

How do I "provoke" such a conflict?

A workaround is doing `git diff -U999999 original.txt > review.txt`, but then you have to delete a lot of `-` and `+` characters at the beginning of every line when reviewing the file.

Comment: that wouldn't be a good practice for a project which has tons of files.

Comment: Why not `git commit -v` when you're committing, and just review the diff?

Answer (score 0):

before you commit, you can just do `git diff path/to/file` to see what has changed.

You can easily setup a graphical tool to use when doing a diff or conflict resolution - see http://adventuresincoding.com/2010/04/how-to-setup-git-to-use-diffmerge for examples.

I use [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/), and when doing a diff, this lets you remove your changes individually, which sounds like the behaviour you want.